# Executing and saving command line

Tags: python, command-line, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Executing command line programs from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python)

How to execute single command within python and save everything between command and prompt to variable?
I've tried following code:

```
import os
var = os.system('ls')
```

Unfortunatelly, my var value is 0 instead 'ls' output.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). Example from the linked documentation:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```