# launching something within python

Tags: python

Ok so as you can see to my question I'm a total newb at python. I'm building a python script and basically I want it to execute this line

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.json input.shp
```

How do I get python to execute this as if I was typing it in my terminal?

Thanks

Comment: Why was this question down voted? Is it not good enough for stack overflow standards?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is that it's because it's a duplicate of previous stack overflow questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python), which could easily be found by (for example) googling "launch command line Python"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import os
os.system('/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.json input.shp')
```

More recently, it is recommended to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) package:

```
subprocess.call(['/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr', '-f',
                 '"GeoJSON"', 'output.json', 'input.shp'])
```

Comment: btw. does python wait for the execution to finish or just fork the process to the os?

Comment: @tomasz: `os.system` waits for it to finish. If you want to fork the process, use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thanks David! I can accept your anser in exactly 9 minutes =)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment, but would like to add to the above answer:
The subprocess package allows for a return handle by which you can determine if the command was executed successfully. This may be important later in your script:

```
import subprocess  
COMMAND = '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.json input.shp'  
return_code = subprocess.call(COMMAND, shell=True)
```