# How can I combine a simple project with scrapy project?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have an example of a scrapy project. it is pretty much default. its folder structure:

```
craiglist_sample/
├── craiglist_sample
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── test.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

When you write  `scrapy crawl craigs -o items.csv -t csv`  to windows command prompt it writes craiglist items and links to console.

I want to create an example.py in main folder and print these items to python console inside it.

I tried

```
 from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl craigs".split())
```

but it writes the same as windows shell output.  How can I make it print only items and list?

test.py
:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craiglist_sample.items import CraiglistSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
##    allowed_domains = ["sfbay.craigslist.org"]
##    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/"]
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.tr.craigslist.org/search/npo?"]

##search\/npo\?s=
    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('s=\d00',),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//span[@class="pl"]')
##        titles = hxs.select("//p[@class='row']")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraiglistSampleItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach could be turning off the default shell output of scrapy and insert a print command inside your parse_items function.

1 - Turn off the debug level in file settings.py

```
LOG_ENABLED = False
```

Documentation about logging levels in Scrapy here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

2 - Add a print command for the items you are interested

```
for titles in titles:
        item = CraiglistSampleItem()
        item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
        item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
        print item ["title"], item ["link"]
```

The shell output will be:

> [u'EXECUTIVE ASSISTANT'] [u'/eby/npo/4848086929.html']
>
> [u'Direct Support Professional'] [u'/eby/npo/4848043371.html']
>
> [u'Vocational Counselor'] [u'/eby/npo/4848042572.html']
>
> [u'Day Program Supervisor'] [u'/eby/npo/4848041846.html']
>
> [u'Educational Specialist'] [u'/eby/npo/4848040348.html']
>
> [u'ORGANIZE WITH GREENPEACE - Grassroots Nonprofit Job!']
>
> [u'/eby/npo/4847984654.html']

EDIT Code for executing from a script

```
import os
os.system('scrapy crawl craigs > log.txt')
```

There are several other ways for executing line program within python.
Check [Executing command line programs from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python) and [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need to run from script. I found this page http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script . that testspider seems to work if I create a .py file in that directory. could  you please modify this spider https://github.com/scrapinghub/testspiders/blob/master/testspiders/spiders/followall.py  for my spider "MySpider" ?

Comment: the proposed modification it is already integrated with your work. Use the script you wrote down: "from scrapy import cmdline cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl craigs".split())"

Comment: sadly no.  my intention was to run scrapy from  a py script.  save that items to a file.  anyway  I accept this answer but i ll be glad if you help me with that

Comment: @St3114 can you add more details (the log) about what it is not working ? What happen if you redirect the output to a file (scrapy crawl craigs > result.txt) ?