# Generate customized PDF documents from a template

Tags: python, pdf

I need to generate a customized PDF copy of a template document.
The easiest way - I thought - was to create a source PDF that has some placeholder text where customization needs to happen , ie `<first_name>` and `<last_name>`, and then replace these with the correct values.

I've searched high and low, but is there really no way of basically taking the source template PDF, replace the placeholders with actual values and write to a new PDF?

I looked at PyPDF2 and ReportLab but neither seem to be able to do so.
Any suggestions? Most of my searches lead to using a Perl app, CAM::PDF, but I'd prefer to keep it all in Python.

Comment: PDF can take many forms, and uses compression, so not that easy. If you want to use alternate rich formats you could go for `.docx` or `.rtf`. docx is zipped xml => text and .rtf is text with markup. html is also a good choice for a template.

Comment: I would nevertheless recommend to have a look at reportlab. As soon as you have figured out the source code for the pdf file you want to generate, making this flexible is pretty straightforward. Have a look at examplese here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/

Comment: You can use ReportLab RML to generate your template (just a text file) and then dynamically add your content. Take a look at the "Going with The Flow" section here http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/

Comment: See also: [How can I replace text in a PDF using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31703037/562769)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this that will work reliably. PDFs are not like HTML: they specify the positioning of text character-by-character. They may not even include the whole font used to render the text, just the characters needed to render the specific text in the document. No library I've found will do nice things like re-wrap paragraphs after updating the text. PDFs are for the most part a display-only format, so you'll be much better off using a tool that turns markup into a PDF than updating the PDF in-place.

If that's not an option, you can create a [PDF form](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html) in something like Acrobat, then use a PDF manipulation library like [iText (AGPL)](http://itextpdf.com/) or [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), which has a nice clojure wrapper called [pdfboxing](https://github.com/dotemacs/pdfboxing#fill-in-pdf-forms) that can handle some of that.

From my experience, Python's support for writing to PDFs is pretty limited. Java has, by far, the best language support. Also, you get what you pay for, so it would probably be worth paying for a iText license if you're using this for commercial purposes. I've had pretty good results writing python wrappers around PDF-manipulation CLI tools like pdfboxing and ghostscript. That will probably be *much* easier for your use case than trying to shoehorn this into Python's PDF ecosystem.

Answer (score 9):

There is no definite solution but I found 2 solutions that works most of the time.

In python https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor gives good results. Here is the example code:

```
# Redact things that look like social security numbers, replacing the
# text with X's.
options.content_filters = [
        # First convert all dash-like characters to dashes.
        (
                re.compile(u"Tom Xavier"),
                lambda m : "XXXXXXX"
        ),

        # Then do an actual SSL regex.
        # See https://github.com/opendata/SSN-Redaction for why this regex is complicated.
        (
                re.compile(r"(?<!\d)(?!666|000|9\d{2})([OoIli0-9]{3})([\s-]?)(?!00)([OoIli0-9]{2})\2(?!0{4})([OoIli0-9]{4})(?!\d)"),
                lambda m : "XXX-XX-XXXX"
        ),
]

# Perform the redaction using PDF on standard input and writing to standard output.
pdf_redactor.redactor(options)
```

Full Example can be found [here](https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor/blob/master/example.py)

In ruby https://github.com/gettalong/hexapdf works for black out text.
Example code:

```
require 'hexapdf'

class ShowTextProcessor < HexaPDF::Content::Processor

  def initialize(page, to_hide_arr)
    super()
    @canvas = page.canvas(type: :overlay)
    @to_hide_arr = to_hide_arr
  end

  def show_text(str)
    boxes = decode_text_with_positioning(str)
    return if boxes.string.empty?
    if @to_hide_arr.include? boxes.string
        @canvas.stroke_color(0, 0 , 0)

        boxes.each do |box|
          x, y = *box.lower_left
          tx, ty = *box.upper_right
          @canvas.rectangle(x, y, tx - x, ty - y).fill
        end
    end

  end
  alias :show_text_with_positioning :show_text

end

file_name = ARGV[0]
strings_to_black = ARGV[1].split("|")

doc = HexaPDF::Document.open(file_name)
puts "Blacken strings [#{strings_to_black}], inside [#{file_name}]."
doc.pages.each.with_index do |page, index|
  processor = ShowTextProcessor.new(page, strings_to_black)
  page.process_contents(processor)
end

new_file_name = "#{file_name.split('.').first}_updated.pdf"
doc.write(new_file_name, optimize: true)

puts "Writing updated file [#{new_file_name}]."
```

In this you can black out text on select text will be visible.

Comment: Did you try the pdf-redactor in python ? i get issues

Comment: The examples on hexapdf site are good and there is a similar one. As far as i understand (not having done this yet) one could also write text into the overlay and have a solid white background, thus overwriting the old, and in that way solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As another solution you may try [Aspose.PDF Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/pdf/python), it provides the feature to replace text in a PDF document.

First thing first, install the Aspose.PDF Cloud SDK for Python

```
pip install asposepdfcloud
```

Sample Code upload PDF file to your cloud storage and replace multiple strings in a PDF document

```
import os 
import asposepdfcloud 
from asposepdfcloud.apis.pdf_api import PdfApi 
 
# Get App key and App SID from https://aspose.cloud 
pdf_api_client = asposepdfcloud.api_client.ApiClient( 
    app_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    app_sid='xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx') 
 
pdf_api = PdfApi(pdf_api_client) 
filename = '02_pages.pdf' 
remote_name = '02_pages.pdf' 
 
#upload PDF file to storage 
pdf_api.upload_file(remote_name,filename) 
 
#Replace Text 
text_replace1 = asposepdfcloud.models.TextReplace(old_value='origami',new_value='aspose',regex='true') 
text_replace2 = asposepdfcloud.models.TextReplace(old_value='candy',new_value='biscuit',regex='true') 
text_replace_list = asposepdfcloud.models.TextReplaceListRequest(text_replaces=[text_replace1,text_replace2]) 
 
response = pdf_api.post_document_text_replace(remote_name, text_replace_list) 
print(response)
```

[image: source and output PDF screenshots]

I'm developer evangelist at aspose.

Comment: It shows the following message when I logged in : Oops! Something went wrong.
There was an error logging into the external provider. The error message is: access_denied

Request Id: 904f9113-d60b-4a50-9645-7284f257a0fe

Comment: @FarhanKhan Please share some more details about the issue you are facing i.e. link or code throwing the error.

Comment: @TilalAhmad do you have a python on prem solution for sensitive documents?

Comment: How would you return the modified PDF as an object under this example?

Comment: @alias51
```from shutil import copyfile
response_download = pdf_api.download_file(remote_file)
copyfile(response_download, remote_file)```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a blank PDF and add a text annotation at the positions where you want the text to be.

You can do that with pypdf ([docs](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/adding-pdf-annotations.html))

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from pypdf.generic import AnnotationBuilder

# Fill the writer with the pages you want
reader = PdfReader("input.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
writer = PdfWriter()
writer.add_page(page)

# Create the annotation and add it
annotation = AnnotationBuilder.free_text(
    "Hello World\nThis is the second line!",
    rect=(50, 550, 200, 650),
    font="Arial",
    bold=True,
    italic=True,
    font_size="20pt",
    font_color="00ff00",
    border_color="0000ff",
    background_color="cdcdcd",
)
writer.add_annotation(page_number=0, annotation=annotation)

# Write the annotated file to disk
with open("annotated-pdf.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```