# How to replace a word in pdf with Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

i want to replace a word in a pdf but when i try to do that it always returns me same pdf. Here is my code block. Currentyle i am using pypdf2 but if is there any suggestion i can switch it. What is the missing part at my code?

```
  with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(file)
        # Encrypt the word in the PDF content
        encrypted_word = self.cipher.encrypt(word_to_encrypt_bytes)
        encrypted_word_b64 = base64.b64encode(encrypted_word)
        # Write the encrypted PDF content to a new PDF file
        pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
        for i in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
            page_content = page.extractText()
            page_content_b = page_content.encode('utf-8')
            page_content_b = page_content_b.replace(word_to_encrypt.encode(), encrypted_word_b64)
            page_content = page_content_b.decode('utf-8')
            pdf_writer.addPage(page)

        output_path = os.path.join(file_dir, file_name_without_ext + '_encryptedm' + ext)
        with open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
            pdf_writer.write(output_file)
```

I want to place a word in my pdf.

Comment: This has already been answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769120/search-and-replace-for-text-within-a-pdf-in-python

Comment: This answer is old and did not solve my problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me when suggesting a solutiuon with PyMuPDF. Example page text:[image]

Suppose we want to correct the misspelling, we can use this snippet:

```py
In [1]: import fitz  # PyMuPDF
...
In [9]: doc=fitz.open("test.pdf")
In [10]: page=doc[0]
In [11]: words=page.get_text("words")  # extract variant by single words
...
In [13]: for word in words:
    ...:     if word[4] == "Currentyle":
    ...:         page.add_redact_annot(word[:4],text="Currently")
    ...:
In [14]: page.apply_redactions()
Out[14]: True
In [15]: doc.ez_save("text-replaced.pdf")
```

Gives us this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more question the how can fix the position of new item? Because as you realized it moves a little bit down and also i have another problem some words not readable maybe because of Turkish alphabet and my font size and font is different how can i fix this?

Comment: Of course I showed the most basic approach only. With a little more effort, you can position the replacing text centered (or otherwise aligned) in the free space. As well it is possible to position the new text vertically at the precise position. You can also extract all font information of the old text, and then use all this for inserting the new text. If you need this level of precision (I realize you do!) more code is obviously needed - but everything can be done. May I invite you to continue this discussion [here](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions/1766).