# Replacing text in a pdf using PyPdf2

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to replace text at a particular location in a pdf using PyPdf2. I tried this:

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf
filename = 'C:/Users/Workstation/Downloads/Sample Text.pdf'
Report = open(filename, 'rb') 
pdfReader = pdf.PdfFileReader(Report)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
txt = pageObj.extractText() 

name = txt[34]
print("name: "+name)
txt[72:80] = "solarsys" #Replacement of text
star_sys = txt[71:83]
print("star_system: "+star_sys)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there any way to get around this

Thanks,

Comment: So you want to replace it the file (i.e. *patch* it), or just in the text you are reading?

Comment: Replace it in the file. Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change/modify/replace text in a PDF using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703037/how-can-i-change-modify-replace-text-in-a-pdf-using-python)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use the `replace()` to replace the text, for example:

```
newTxt = txt.replace('#what word you want to repalce', '# which word you want to replace it with')
```

and this code will make the text file replace and save:

```
#input file
test = open("Test.txt", "w+")
#output file to write the result to
test2 = open("Test2.txt", "wt")
#for each line in the input file
for line in test:
    #read replace the string and write to output file
    test2.write(line.replace('replace', 'replaced'))
#close input and output files
test.close()
test2.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, does this save the document with the edits or is there something else I should do?

Comment: Im not 100% sure, give me a couple of minutes ill test it out using my python documents

Comment: Looks like it won't work but you can do something else to change the text and save it, ill post another answer

Comment: I think you the files in the second answers are text files and not pdf's. Thanks,

Comment: I think it will still work, but you might want to double check

Comment: Do I have to create a new blank pdf file to store the results

Comment: Yes, you have the first pdf file as the word which you want to replace and then it puts the replaced word in a new file

Comment: Better don't "patch" PDF files by hand! Search for another library to do it.