# How can I replace text from a PDF with Python?

Tags: python

im triying to replace a text from a PDF with PyPDF2, but I can't found many information about it. So I need to use other library? or I need left this idea from my head?

Comment: Is this a one-time thing, or is this something you'll need to do regularly?  If you decompress the PDF, the PDF protocol is readaable enough that you can use a text editor to "fix it".

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue was already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902765/replacing-text-in-a-pdf-using-pypdf2)

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf
filename = 'C:/Sample Text.pdf'
Report = open(filename, 'rb') 
pdfReader = pdf.PdfFileReader(Report)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
txt = pageObj.extractText()
```

this is how you extract the text

```
newTxt = txt.replace('#what word you want to repalce', '# which word you want to replace it with')
```

and this is how you replace your text

Comment: Well, that's how you retrieve the text and change it.  That doesn't address how to change the document

Comment: You just write the new pdf with changed data

Comment: It's a nice theory, but that is by far the most difficult part of the question.  Once you've extracted the text, you have NO CLUE where that text was found.  You have lost any connection to the original text object, so you can't even delete the original text.  That's why your answer is not useful.