# How can I make a program that can run cmd commands in python3.x

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd

I trying to make a program that can access other computers in the same network by using the cmd command. I have an administrator password that work in all computers in our network. But I don't know how to make a program that includes cmd commands? Which module should I use or are there other ways to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python

Answer (score 1):

Use python's os module.

```
import os
os.system('dir')
os.system('ping 127.0.0.1')
```