# Can a Python script enter commands on the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an executable script, let's call it script.py. I am trying to run a series of commands within the terminal starting with

```
python3 ./differentscript.py console
```

which will allow me to type in additional commands.

However, I was wondering if this can be automated i.e. have my script somehow output and execute the commands?

**Edit: I took a look at the links commented below; can someone provide an example of what this would look like?**

Comment: `subprocess`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python `os.system`: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17017/how-insert-a-command-line-command-in-python-script/17029

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing command line programs from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python)

Comment: Thanks for the links guys. I am able to output and execute that command line. However, how do I get it to call multiple commands in succession?

Answer (score 0):

@Chen Xie

If you want to call a few commands at once, you can call it like below:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo First&echo Second&echo Third', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
```

It's not a Pythonic solution, but it works.